# Scientific notations with negative powers for plotting

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, ticks

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 100}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, ScientificForm@#} & /@ 
    Range[0., 100., 30.], {#, ScientificForm@#} & /@ 
    Range[0., 100^2, 1000.]}, PlotRange -> All]

PowerTicks[label_][min_, max_] := 
  Block[{min10, max10}, min10 = Floor[Log10[min]];
   max10 = Ceiling[Log10[max]];
   Join[Table[{10^i, 
      If[label, Superscript[10, i], Spacer[{0, 0}]]}, {i, min10, 
      max10}], 
    Flatten[
     Table[{k 10^i, 
       Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.005, 0.`}, {Thickness[0.001`]}}, {i, min10, 
       max10}, {k, 9}], 1]]];

ListLogLogPlot[Range[20]^3, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{PowerTicks[True], 
    PowerTicks[False]}, {PowerTicks[True], PowerTicks[False]}}]
```

The above code works very well for the positive powers. Could some one please check it how does it change for the negative powers. More specific, on both axes the scales should be ranging {10^-5, 10^-4....10^0, 10^1, 10^2,...10^5}. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The axes are scaled to the data. If only want to change the axes with the same data you may use `PlotRange`:

```
ListLogLogPlot[Range[20]^3, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{PowerTicks[True], 
    PowerTicks[False]}, {PowerTicks[True], PowerTicks[False]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{10^-5, 10^5}, {10^-5, 10^5}}]
```

[image]

However, MMA does this automatically if the data span this range. E.g.:

```
dat = Join[(1/Range[40])^3, Range[40]^3];
dat = Transpose[{dat, dat}];
ListLogLogPlot[dat, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{PowerTicks[True], 
    PowerTicks[False]}, {PowerTicks[True], PowerTicks[False]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! My data includes the negative powers, so the the second option is relevent to me. By the way, how do you get the tick markers more darker in your images above. Mine are the same, but dimmer.

Comment: Well, I did not do anything and did not even realize it. But in between you edited your code, `PowerTicks` is no more working.

Comment: So, you are not using PowerTicks from my code above?

Comment: Yes, I am using `PowerTicks` but if I try my code it does no more run. And you changed  your code. Therefore I assume you changed `PowerTicks` as I did not change my part.

Comment: Hubel: No, I have not changed anything, I guess someone else might have changed it.