# Axes ticks scaled in powers of ten

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, labeling, ticks

I'm trying to plot the solution of an ODE and I would like to have the ticks in powers of ten. Although, this happes automatically from Mathematica for small orders, such as `10^(-6)`, it doesn't happen for orders of `10^(-5)` and smaller. I tried to fix it in FrameTicks, but it shows as a fraction. The code is the following:

```
y =.;Sol = NDSolve[{D[y[x], x] == -4*10^(-2)*(y[x] - 10)*y[x], 
y[0] == 0.00999}, {y}, {x, 0, 0.000125}];
Plot1 = Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. First[Sol]], {x, 0, tend},MaxRecursion -> 15, PlotPoints -> {200000, 100000}, Mesh -> False,AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Green,FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontFamily -> "MS Serif",FontSize -> 22],Style["y", FontFamily -> "MS Serif", FontSize -> 22]},RotateLabel -> True,Frame -> {{Automatic, False}, {Automatic,False}}];

Show[Plot1, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.000125}, {0.00999, 0.01}}, MaxRecursion -> 1000, PlotPoints -> {200000, 100000},AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, RotateLabel -> True,LabelStyle -> {20, GrayLevel[0]},FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.00999, 0.009992, 0.009994, 0.009996, 0.009998,0.01}, None},{{0, 0.0000625, 0.000125}, None}}]
```

[image]

Is there a way to fix the tics in the plot?

Comment: Do you mean like `LogPlot[]` or `LogLogPlot[]`? There's only one power of ten that's showing for `y`: Do you want only one tick mark?  [Or, wild guess, do you want the ticks in scientific notation?)

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/about-the-number-format-in-ticks

Comment: I was hoping to have something like `1.25*10^(-4)` in the x-axis and `9.99*10^(-3)`in the y-axis. Is this possible?

Comment: [This Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240736/scientific-notations-with-negative-powers-for-plotting) uses `FrameTicks -> {{{#, ScientificForm@#} & /@ {0, 0.00999, 0.009992, 0.009994, 0.009996, 0.009998, 0.01}, None}, {{#, ScientificForm@#} & /@ {0, 0.0000625, 0.000125}, None}}`

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you possibly know how can I force the origin to be in the left-bottom corner of the plot instead of starting a bit higher and righter? Sometimes it does it automatically and some others not with no obvious reason (at least to me).

Comment: Have you seen the option `AxesOrigin`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129985/discussion-between-vicky-and-michael-e2).

Comment: Yes, I've tried it already. In the code I've posted I have AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}. I just tried AxesOrigin -> {0, 0.00999}, but I get the same. I have a nb file that it is fine. I copied and pasted it and changed some parameters and then I got the spaces.

Comment: It seems to be the PlotRange. Must be defined in both Plot1 and Show (instead of having PlotRange -> All in Plot1). Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: Why do not you plot, say, `y-0.00999` at the y-axis and `x-0.0000625` at the y-axis?  Then the numbers at the ticks, would be much easier to see.